# Creating full, global clang+llvm environment

Tags: linux, llvm

What is the easiest way to setup full Clang, libc++ and LLVM as default global toolchain? All of my attempts to build it, in most of the configurations I could think of, resulted in working Clang, but it didn't use libc++ headers, but default GCC's libstd++'s ones, resulting in numerous faults in incompatible pieces of library code.

I would like it working out of the box, without having to do magic in `.bashrc` or passing all those `-stdlib=libc++` and `-lc++` to compiler and linker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging on how LLVM and Clang have been integrated into FreeBSD's base, i think you will need to hack Clang's internals to set library and headers paths (`lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp`) for your system.

Using libc++ as default definitely needs changing the code (grep `lib/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.cpp` for "UseLibcxx"). You will probably need to hack system linker too to change `-lstdc++` to `-lc++`.

Personally, i'd recommend you just setting CC, CXX, CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and other vars to achieve same result without much hassle. It works for me flawlessly on FreeBSD.